# Passing key inside key in url params

Tags: url, url-routing

There is a client need to pass entire query params inside one key.
For example if I had something like this ?t=a&b=c&d=e.I need to pass these params in one key named z.
So now key is z and it's value is ?t=a&b=c&d=e.
Is this even possible and if possible then how?

Answer (score 0):

You should encode `?t=a&b=c&d=e`. For example, encode in IPython:

```
In [1]: from urllib import urlencode

In [2]: data = {'z':'?t=a&b=c&d=e'}

In [3]: print urlencode(data)
z=%3Ft%3Da%26b%3Dc%26d%3De
```

What you want is `z=%3Ft%3Da%26b%3Dc%26d%3De`.